# How does dialogflow chooses between static responses and webhook responses?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to build a bot service using google's dialogflow. I have already written an intent and that is having a web hook and static responses also. My question is how does dialogflow decides between static responses and whether to invoke the webhook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a webhook defined, and you have the "Enable webhook call for this intent" switched on, it will call the webhook. If your webhook returns a response, it will send that response to the user.

If you have the switch off, or if your webhook does not return anything (either because it times out or you choose not to send anything), then it will use the replies you have set in the Intent.

Comment: Thanks @Prisoner. So there is no way I can redirect it to the set replies if my web hook is enabled and it returns some response. No way at all, right?

Comment: No, there isn't. (How would it know when to send and when not to send?)

Comment: Thanks @Prisoner, may be for a basic 1:1 map of the text replies with the user queries may have done this, in case the map to any reply doesn't exists with the query, the web hook could have been called then instead. I understand that would have been difficult though may be for the AI to understand similar kind of queries from user. Anyways thanks.

Comment: What happens when there is a custom payload (default response)(which is usually stored in the fulfillment messages). If from webhook I send back a fulfillmentText, will the default payload be discarded or will it still work?

Comment: I have not robustly tested this, but as I understand it, anything set in the response section in Dialogflow is ignored if you send back a  response payload from a webhook. You may wish to try it and, if you encounter issue, open a new question with as many details as you can.